# disable submit button after form submit and save the disable state of the button

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have a page which has a form with questions and answers, upon submit I want to disable to button, and the user is taken to a thanks page. From that page when the user hits back  button on browser he comes back to the form page(ques and ans page), at that point since he has already submitted the form i want the button to remain disabled to prevent from retaking the ques. I have the below code, but it is not serving the purpose sometimes its only working in FF and not in chrome. (upon going back). Any ideas here please? Thanks

```
<cfif (isdefined("form.isSubmitted") and form.isSubmitted neq "")>
            <div id="intro">                                         
                        <div class="headline">
                            <h1>Thank You for Taking the test!</h1>
                        </div>   
              <div id="welcome2" class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs"> Thank you for taking the test </div>   
                                <div class="start">
                                    <a href="/xyz.cfm" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-submit btn-sd-yellow-grad bold margin-bottom-20 rounded-4x">
                                Create Account                          
                                    </a>
                                </div>      

        <cfelse>
    ques ans form
    </cfif>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function form_submit() {
            var all_quest_done = true;
            var question_count = document.getElementById('ques_count').value;
            var ans_found;
            var radio_answer;
            var ans_count;
            for (ques_index = 1; ques_index <= ques_count; ques_index++) {
                radio_answers = document.getElementsByName('ques' + ques_index);
                //alert(ques_index);
                ans_found = false;
                for (ans_index = 0; ans_index < radio_ans.length; ans_index++) {
                    if (radio_answers[ans_index].checked) {
                        ans_found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!ans_found) {
                    all_quest_done= false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        var response = true;
        if (!all_quest_done) {
                var confirm_message = 'Not all the questions have been done!'
                    do you want to submit?';
                response = confirm(confirm_message);
             if (response){
                  document.getElementById("qSubmit").disabled = true;
                  return true;
             }else{
                return false;
             }
            }
        </script>
        <form action="abc.cfm" method="post" name="my_form" onSubmit="return form_submit();">
         <input type radio>
        Form with questions and answers goes here
        <input id="qSubmit" type="submit" value="I'M done" name="submit_now" class="btn" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the page the user is being redirected to?

Comment: I have added the page user is being directed to

Comment: And where is it? Is it the same file? And what is that `cfif` tag and `cfelse`?

Comment: Yes it is the same file, this is a coldfusion form, cfifi cfelse, is handling the form submission since it is submitting to itself

Comment: My question is after the user submits the form and sees the thanks page, at that point if he hits back button(browser) how can we still save the disabled state of the submit button. Is it possible to do that.

Comment: Try using a cookies to block voting again. Also you can use php and manage a database that registers every vote (or questions or whatever that is). Also I can't find the lines that actually save the submited data. Where are the lines that save the data that was sent?

Comment: That is being done thru a coldfusion function on server side. The page is really big (not able to post entire code) , so it is like if (form.submit)insert into db endif..im not sure how to that using cookies can you pleasr give me an example?

Comment: is it inserting that data into a database? And if yes with what language? php?

Comment: Yes, the selected answers data, using coldfusion

Comment: Give me 10 minutes I will write an Example script. Do you want that they will be able to submit this form only one time per IP, or how do you want it to work?

Comment: 1. this is a sample test which an anonymous user is taking, upon submit im inserting the user id (which im storing in sesison)into a table; followed by all other test data he takes. 2. After submitting the form user is taken to thansk page where is needs to register to see the result. 3. Basically i just need to prevent him from retaking the testin that session.4. He can come back later and retake it. hope this makes sense thanks in advace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88413/discussion-between-mor-haviv-and-user747291).

Comment: @MorHaviv, the question is tagged ColdFusion.  The language being used is ColdFusion Markup Language.