# Coldfusion form submit disable submit button

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I am looking for some advice here. I have posted a question earlier [Disable submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316116/disable-submit-button-after-form-submit-and-save-the-disable-state-of-the-button?noredirect=1#comment52517829_32316116).

1. I have a form that submits to itself and looks liek below

   ```
   <cfif isdefined(form.submit)>
       thank you for taking the test
   <cfelse>
      Actual form with radio buttons, ques, ans
   </cfif>
   ```
2. After now, after the user takes the test and hits submit and is on the thanks portion of the form. At that point if he hits back button on the browser, he is still seeing the form.
3. I have the server side validations in place at this point where if he refreshes the form he will be taken to the thanks page again.
4. I tried to disable the submit button, but this is not working always on all browsers.
5. Can anyone please tell me what me be the best thing to do in this case.
6. Should i do a history.forward(); on the page? so that when ever the user hits back browser button he still stays on the same page.
7. Or should I clear the cache in the this manner, so that when the user hits back button he doesnt see the form but just stays on the thanks page.

   ```
   <cfoutput>
       <cfheader name="expires" value="#now()#">
       <cfheader name="pragma" value="no-cache">
       <cfheader name="cache-control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
   </cfoutput>
   ```
8. Or is there something im missing and these above are just hacks and should not be done. Your replies are greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest experimenting with 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

If the user has a unique id then you can check to see if they have already completed the survey by looking up a database record or similar. Otherwise a simple option is to set a session variable once they have submitted the form. The session is time limited and will be different in a new browser session, so is not a guaranteed way to stop the same person submitting the survey again, but something like this may solve your issue.

```
 <cfif structKeyExists(form,"submit") or structKeyExists(session, "completed")>
     <cfif !structKeyExists(session, "completed")>
         <!--- do validation etc here, if all good then --->
         <cflock scope="session" timeout="5">
             <cfset session.completed = true>
         </cflock>
     </cfif>
     thank you for taking the test
 <cfelse>
     Actual form with radio buttons, ques, ans
 </cfif>
```

Alternatively you could do it by using a cookie (`cfcookie`) instead of using a session.

Comment: thanks for the input. I am doing something like above, but this is not preventing the user to NOT see the form when he hits the browser back button...

Comment: you just need to check for `<cfif structKeyExists(session, "completed")>`. If it does then you know that they have already completed it so redirect them.

Comment: That would only apply to a page request.  Using the browser to go back does not cause a page to be requested.